# %252F in the URL

Tags: views, media

I have imagecache installed and I'm using views. In my fields in views I have selected one of the presets for my images to resize. When I try to view my completed page the path to the thumbnail is incorrect. It links to http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/album/%252Fimages/...

Where does that %252F come from? How can I fix this to show the correct URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%2f` is the url encoding of `/`, if you have `%252f` seems a double encode of the specific string. I guess a bug of imagecache Module, or/and some intermediate module using an encode process.

Also, this documentation related with Drupal drupal_urlencode could be useful to understand the case when exist `//` that is `/%252F` http://api.acquia.com/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_urlencode/6

Answer (score 1):

I believe `%252f` represents a slash `/` in URL encoding. When data is passed in urls it is encoded because only certain characters can be in urls, so a mixture of allowed characters are used to represent certain characters that would otherwise be disallowed. Considering that this is a slash `/`, it's likely that you have a beginning or trailing slash somewhere where it doesn't belong - maybe in a field in which you identify a path - resulting in two consecutive slashes, the second being encoded, so look for that.